# How to create date range properly and rearrange (with crosstab / pivot) table?

Tags: python, pandas

Advice needed.

I have a df with the structure like this one:

```
Video | Start              | End                | Duration |  
vid1  |2018-10-02 16:00:29 |2018-10-02 20:07:05 |   246    |  
vid2  |2018-10-04 16:03:08 |2018-10-04 16:10:11 |     7    |  
vid3  |2018-10-04 10:13:40 |2018-10-06 12:07:38 |   113    |
```

My goal is to create TS index between start.min() and end.max() with given frequency and rearrange table in the next output with the values in cell shown difference between start time of the video and current index:

```
Date                 | vid1    | vid2    | vid3    |  
2018-10-02 16:00:00  | someval | someval | someval |
2018-10-02 16:10:00  | someval | someval | someval |
2018-10-02 16:20:00  | someval | someval | someval |
2018-10-02 16:30:00  | someval | someval | someval |
```

I have two problems:
1. My datetime index that I obtain with the

```
 pd.date_range(start = df['Start'].min(),
                    end = df['End'].max(),
                    freq='10T')
```

doesn't produce sequenial dates while applying and stacking but generates only intervals for days where videos were generated (i mean, if one video was generated 2018-10-02 and another 2018-10-04 i obtain TSs only for these two days while I need 2018-10-03 date to be included too).

2. I can't get how to apply function for calculating how much time in minutes passed from the start time of the video till the current index.

So any clues are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt:

```
vid1_start, vid2_start, vid3_start = df.loc[df.video=='vid1', 'start'].iloc[0], \
df.loc[df.video=='vid2', 'start'].iloc[0], df.loc[df.video=='vid3', 'start'].iloc[0]

vid1_end, vid2_end, vid3_end = df.loc[df.video=='vid1', 'end'].iloc[0], \
df.loc[df.video=='vid2', 'end'].iloc[0], df.loc[df.video=='vid3', 'end'].iloc[0]

x = df.set_index('start').reindex(pd.date_range(df.start.min(), df.end.max(), freq='10T'))


x['vid1'] = (x.index - vid1_start).seconds
x['vid2'] = (x.index - vid2_start).seconds
x['vid3'] = (x.index - vid3_start).seconds

x.loc[x.index > vid1_end, 'vid1'] = np.NaN
x.loc[(x.index > vid2_end) | (x.index < vid2_start), 'vid2'] = np.NaN
x.loc[(x.index > vid3_end) | (x.index < vid3_start), 'vid3'] = np.NaN

x = x.drop(columns=['video', 'end', 'duration'])
```

This gives you `x` which looks like this:

```
                        vid1    vid2    vid3
2018-10-02 16:00:29     0.0     NaN     NaN
2018-10-02 16:10:29     600.0   NaN     NaN
2018-10-02 16:20:29     1200.0  NaN     NaN
2018-10-02 16:30:29     1800.0  NaN     NaN
2018-10-02 16:40:29     2400.0  NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...
2018-10-06 11:20:29     NaN     NaN     4009.0
2018-10-06 11:30:29     NaN     NaN     4609.0
2018-10-06 11:40:29     NaN     NaN     5209.0
2018-10-06 11:50:29     NaN     NaN     5809.0
2018-10-06 12:00:29     NaN     NaN     6409.0
```

Not sure what you mean about `date_range` omitting values not found in the original data; it will generate all dates at given `freq` between `start` and `end`.

Comment: Thanks! Got an idea and customized a little